# Adding a number to the 2nd element of each pair in a list of pairs

Tags: list-manipulation

I can't figure out how to add a constant value to a list. The list to which the `data` variable is bound was imported from a CSV file with 2 columns.

For example,

```
data = {{0.01, 0.02}, {0.08, 0.09}, {0.02, -0.05}, {0.03, 0.1}, ...}
```

How would I add a scalar value (e.g., +0.01) to the 2nd element of each pair?

The transformed data can be stored in a new variable `data1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try

```
#+{0,0.01}&/@{{0.01,0.02},{0.08,0.09},{0.02,-0.05},{0.03,0.1}}
```

> {{0.01, 0.03}, {0.08, 0.1}, {0.02, -0.04}, {0.03, 0.11}}

in other words

```
data1=#+{0,0.01}&/@data
```

Comment: Thank you. That's what I needed.

Comment: I'm glad I helped !

Answer (score 3):

Not the fastest, but simple to understand:

```
m = {{0.01,0.02},{0.08,0.09},{0.02,-0.05},{0.03,0.1}};
TranslationTransform[{0,.01}] @ m
```

> {{0.01, 0.03}, {0.08, 0.1}, {0.02, -0.04}, {0.03, 0.11}}

Much faster is to use [`Transpose`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose) twice:

```
Transpose[Transpose[m] + {0., .01}]
```

> {{0.01, 0.03}, {0.08, 0.1}, {0.02, -0.04}, {0.03, 0.11}}

Using [`Compile`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Compile) would be even faster.

Comment: Excellent approaches. I will definitely try this out for very large sets of data, which I have.

Answer (score 3):

`MapAt` does exactly that:

`data1 = MapAt[# + 0.01 &, data, {All, 2}]`

Answer (score 2):

```
data = {{0.01, 0.02}, {0.08, 0.09}, {0.02, -0.05}, {0.03, 0.1}};
```

Using `Threaded` (new in 13.1)

```
data1 = data + Threaded[{0, 0.01}]
```

{{0.01, 0.03}, {0.08, 0.1}, {0.02, -0.04}, {0.03, 0.11}}

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative way to do it. I am not sure if it is fast though.

```
data = {{0.01, 0.02}, {0.08, 0.09}, {0.02, -0.05}, {0.03, 0.1}};
data[[All, 2]] += 0.01;
data
```

> {{0.01, 0.03}, {0.08, 0.1}, {0.02, -0.04}, {0.03, 0.11}}

Answer (score 1):

```
data = {{0.01, 0.02}, {0.08, 0.09}, {0.02, -0.05}, {0.03, 0.1}};
```

Using `SubsetMap`:

```
SubsetMap[# + 0.01 &, data, {All, 2}]

(*{{0.01, 0.03}, {0.08, 0.1}, {0.02, -0.04}, {0.03, 0.11}}*)
```